# compare "book the first" and "the first book"

Tags: phrases

I started to read a book. In first pages It says:

"A Series of Unfortunate Events

Book the First

The Bad Beginning"

Why it says "Book the First" instead of "The First Book"? Is there any note about these kind of forms?

Comment: It would appear that Charles Dickens' *Hard Times* is divided in a similar fashion: https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/hardtimes/

Comment: It's a stylistic choice.  I'm familiar with these books, they have a polished style with humourously absurd situations.  So "Book The First" means the same thing as "The First Book" but sounds more old-fashioned in a prim and proper way.

Comment: HG Wells used 'Chapter the First' and I have seen 'Part the First' as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a deliberate stylistic choice, it sounds serious, but usually intended ironically. Some Old English books have titles like this, using Old English grammar.  It is a joke

For example Lewis Carroll divided his nonsense poem "The Hunting of the Snark" as "Fit the First", "Fit the Second".  It is a joke to use titles from Ancient Saxon poetry in a joke poem about hunting an imaginary creature. (for the snark was a boojum, you see).  This style was also used in Victorian times by authors like Charles Dickens.

The author of the "series of unfortunate events" is also using this fake-serious style as a joke. It suggests that the book is a classic from 150 years ago, which is the style that the author wants to give.